# convert Map<Object, List<Object>> dataMap to json using java 8

Tags: json, java-8

I have a map with following prototype

```
Map<Device, List<Message>> dataMap
```

I want to convert it into json using java 8.

i had tried this :

```
public static String getJson(Map<Device, List<Message>> data) {
    String json = "{" + data.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> "\"" + e.getKey().getId() + "\"" + ":\"" + String.valueOf(e.getValue()) + "\"")
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + "}";
    return json;
```

but it is retutning only one record when i am trying to convert more than 1 record in map.

e.g.

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapData = new HashMap<>();
mapData.put("Avy", Arrays.asList("Hello", "Hi"));
mapData.put("Sam", Arrays.asList("Good"));
```

returns

> "{\"1001\":\"[Message{message='You have scheduled monthly check-up.'}]\"}"

Comment: Try using Gson library's toJson funciton. Its easy and all the logic is hidden.

Comment: i understood the problem.this problem occurs when  . encounteed in the message

Comment: Thanks ...Gson will be great approach.

Comment: Added it in the answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use GSON library's toJSON function.
Its easy and hides the unwanted complexities odf doing it  manually.
In this case, you might have to use TypeToken.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type classType = new TypeToken<Map<Device, List<Message>>>(){}.getType();
String dataMapJson= gson.toJson(dataMap, classType);
```

Haven't tested the code. This is just to give you a gist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put( "name", "Mars" );
    data.put( "age", 32 );
    data.put( "city", "NY" );
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.putAll( data );
    System.out.printf( "JSON: %s", json.toString(2) );
output::

JSON: {
  "age": 32,
  "name": "Mars",
  "city": "NY"
}
```

You can also try to use Google's [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Google's GSON is the best library available to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation.

Comment: Jackson is also a valid alternative https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson